# Nginx don't redirect to nodeJs port

Tags: nginx, node.js, vps

I have a NodeJS app on port 8080 and my Nginx file look like this :

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;


        root /var/www/html;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;


        server_name _;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

But when I go to :
`XX.XXX.XXX`
I have a 403 error, I need to go to :
`XX.XXX.XXX:8080`
What is wrong ?

Comment: Are there any errors in the logs? Can you open address xx.xxx.xxx:8080 directly in browser?

Comment: yes xx.xxx.xxx:8080 is working, but I need to add ":8080" to get to my website. I want to be on root "xx.xxx.xxx"

Comment: Good, then 403 comes from nginx. Now what about logs?

Comment: 2021/04/21 17:44:16 [error] 28659#28659: *17 access forbidden by rule, client: x.x.x.x, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "xx.xx.xx.xx"

Comment: Please see similar issue resolved by changing additional configuration file: https://serverfault.com/questions/757220/access-forbidden-by-rule-on-nginx Probably you have something similar, since you can access port 8080 directly and nginx does not complaint about upstream server inaccessible.